# Soaking liver in milk: in or out of the fridge?

Tags: food-safety, meat, liver

When soaking pork liver in milk for 2 hours, should I place it in the fridge or at room temperature? I'm worried it might go bad, as my room is pretty hot in the summer...

Comment: What reason would you have for not soaking it in the fridge?

Comment: I have soaked calf liver in milk for 3 days in the fridge, never taking it out. Will it be safe to eat if I cook it under the broiler as I usually do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can safely soak it at room temperature, but why would you?  There's no reason not to refrigerate.

Meat is safe for about 2 hours in the temperature danger zone of 40F/4C to 140F/60C. Beyond that, it should be cooked or refrigerated.  So, if you do decide to soak at room temperature you should cook or chill it promptly.

Comment: Well, I thought the process is slowed when cooled.

Comment: @drozzy Yes, it may be slightly slower, but you can safely soak overnight in the fridge, which lets the process proceed further.